# Parameter not found in collection my SQL stored procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have parameters like that

```
        Mysql_param[0] = new MySqlParameter("p_MainID", SqlDbType.Int);
        Mysql_param[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32 ( MID);

        Mysql_param[1] = new MySqlParameter("p_DetailID", SqlDbType.Int);
        Mysql_param[1].Value = Convert.ToInt32( DID);

        Mysql_param[2] = new MySqlParameter("p_UserID ", SqlDbType.Int);
        Mysql_param[2].Value = Convert.ToInt32(USERID== "" ? "0" : USERID);

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(pobj_cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
```

I have stored procedure like that

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_HistoryInsertion`(
       IN p_MainID  int 
      , IN p_DetailID int
      , IN p_USERID   int
)
    INSERT INTO history (`MainID`, `DetailID`, )
    VALUES (p_MainID, p_DetailID);
```

But I get an error:

> {"Parameter 'p_USERID' not found in the collection."}

Actually `p_USER` is auto increment in database that is later used in update and delete and select operations so I have to pass it as its is in every procedure so the same error related to that city_id is present in every where more then 6 stored procedures

The datatypes are `INT` for every column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed in your code is that there is an extra space after parameter name "CITY_ID". Your parameter name is mentioned is "CITY_ID " which I think should "CITY_ID".

That should resolve your issue. If you still see the issue then look at the below solution.

You have parameters p_CMP_ID,p_BRC_ID, and p_CITY_ID in yours stored procedure.
But as per your code  you are creating only one parameter with correct name "p_CMP_ID".

Other two parameters have different names than the expected ones.

Changing parameter name "BRC_ID" to "p_BRC_ID" and "CITY_ID" to "p_CITY_ID" should solve your issue.

Thanks and regards,
Chetan Ranpariya

Blockquote

Comment: yes this is also a problem `pobj_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(MySQLParam[x].ParameterName  , MySQLParam[x].Value );`